# How do I set up a comment reply feature in react.js in these codes?

Tags: node.js, reactjs

So, I am using react, nodejs and mongodb to build a basic blog application.

So far, I have been able to add the comment feature and users can create, delete and edit comments. But I wanted to add the ability to reply to a comment. I added a 'Reply' text inside the area where I mapped the array of comments in my react.js component. So, when you click on the 'Reply' it toggles the textbox for reply. That means on first click, the textbox to reply to that specific comment shows up, on second click, that textbox hides.
The problem now is that the toggle is working for all the mapped array of comments. I am trying to assign the specific '_id' to the 'Reply' text and pass it to the textbox for the user to write their reply to that specific comment using the '_id'. This should prevent the reply textbox from toggling for all the comments at the same time. How best can I get this done? Here are my codes:

**The useState that hides and shows the textbox**

```
 const [showReply, setShowReply] = useState(false)
```

**The function that toggles the useState**

```
 const handleShowReplyComment = (id) =>{
console.log(id)
if(id){
    setShowReply(!showReply)
    console.log(id)
}

}
```

This function picks the '_id' of the comment that I clicked. But how to pass that '_id' to the textbox is my challenge.

```
  return (
    <div className="comment">
        <h5 className='users-comment'>Users comments</h5>
            {comments.map((singleComment, index)=>{
                console.log(singleComment)
                const {author, commentdescription, _id, createdAt} = singleComment
                
                return(
                    <>

                        {updateComment == _id ? 
                         <div className='comment-div' key={_id} >
        
                    <textarea className='comment-wrapper' type='text' 
                    onChange={(e) => setCommentDescription(e.target.value)} value={commentdescription2}>

                    </textarea>
                    <button className={isLoading ? 'comment-btn-no-cursor comment-btn': 'comment-btn'}onClick={() => handleCommentUpdate(_id)}>Update Post</button>
                    {error && <p>what happened?</p> }
                    </div>
                        :
                         <div className='displayed-comments'key={_id}>
                            
                            <div className="commentPic">
                                
                                <img className="user-pics" src={PF + singleComment.author.profilePicture} alt="" />
                                  
                            </div>
                            <div className="comment-info">
                                <div className="comment-author-div">
                                    <div className='comment-author-date-info'>
                                        <h4 className="comment-author">{singleComment.author.username}</h4>
                                         <p className="comment-date">{new Date(singleComment.createdAt).toDateString()}
                                            </p>
                                    </div>
                                   {
                                       singleComment.author.username == user?.username &&  <div className="comment-edit-delete-div">
                                         <i className="singlePostIcon fas fa-edit" onClick={() => {setUpdateComment(_id); setCommentDescription(commentdescription)}}  ></i>
                                            <i className={isLoading? "cursor-not-allowed singlePostIcon far fa-trash-alt":"singlePostIcon far fa-trash-alt" } onClick={() => handleCommentDelete(_id)}  ></i>

                                    </div>
                                   }
                                   
                                </div>
                                <p className="comment-content">{singleComment.commentdescription}</p>
                                <div>
                                    
                                </div>
                                <h5 className="reply-comment" onClick={() => handleShowReplyComment(_id)}>Reply</h5> //this is the text with the toggle onClick function that toggles the useState called 'showReply'
                                
                                {showReply &&  <div className='reply-div'>//this is the textbox with the useState 'showReply'.
                                    <textarea className='comment-wrapper '>


                                    </textarea>
                                </div>}
                               
                            </div>
                            
                            
                        </div>
                    
                        }
                         </>
                )
          
            })}

    </div>
)
```

Comment: I'd recommend to move the reply logic to a comment component, this way each will have its own state and it should solve your problem.

Comment: Okay, this sounds interesting. WIll try it out. Thank you very much.